# Powershell - Add ASP.NET 4.8 via powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am using this powershell script to install and IIS server on a Windows 10 machines:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpErrors
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpLogging
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-LoggingLibraries
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestMonitor
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Security
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestFiltering
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Performance
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Metabase
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-BasicAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WindowsAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-StaticContent
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASP
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ServerSideIncludes
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NETExtensibility48

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET48
```

However, once I reach `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET48` I get an error that states `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name IIS-ASPNET48 is unknown`. How can I install ASP.NET 4.8 using powershell?

Comment: Please run `Get-WindowsFeature` to learn what are the proper names, https://blog.lextudio.com/install-iis-10-on-windows-via-powershell-96baf95efc2e Microsoft won't magically give you `IIS-ASPNET48` when there is none.

Comment: you could try to use this command:`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45` and `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45`

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 11 I use CMD command `DISM /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45` to enable the Windows feature "**Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > ASP.NET 4.8**".

[image]